# Resize a 2 dimensional numpy array while treating sublists as individual values

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
[[-2. -2.]
 [ 2. -2.]
 [-2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.]]
```

I have an np array like this and I want it to be shaped like

```
[[-2. -2.][ 2. -2.]
 [-2.  2.][ 2.  2.]]
```

i.e as a grid of size 2x2 where each element is an 'ordered pair'.

Comment: Does `np.reshape((2, 2, 2))` give the desires shape? Otherwise I don't see the difference between the two.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal I don't think thats the result I want. Basically what is the best way to get an array of coordinates from this? In normal python each sublist would be 'set'. But in numpy the only unit for this seems to be the number. I want it to act as if each sub array like [-2,2] is one value and when I shape it to 2x2 it shapes each [a,b] pair to that.

Comment: I would recommend changing the inner values to tuples and reshaping to (2, 2) if the values are only useful together.

Comment: You could make a (2,2) array of object dtype, where each object element is a tuple.  But for most uses such an array is inferior to the (2,2,2) integer dtype.  If you want a list with sublists that are "sets", stick with lists.

Comment: Ok I will try to set dtype to tuple. I was using tuples before but numpy wasn't 'recognizing' the tuples (ie it broke them apart into individual values), so I guess that is what dtype tuple would fix. I am just trying to output this data not do operations on it so I don't think I need the full 2,2,2 array unless this offers something else useful

Answer (score 0):

You may need to "transpose" or "reorder" or "permute" the axes (all similar words for the same thing). You can do that with [`np.ndarray.tranpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html) or [`np.ndarray.swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.swapaxes.html) Example:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [-2, -2],
    [ 2, -2],
    [-2,  2],
    [ 2,  2]
])

out = arr.reshape(2, 2, 2).swapaxes(0, 1)
```

out:

```
array([[[-2, -2],
        [-2,  2]],

       [[ 2, -2],
        [ 2,  2]]])
```